# what this method does - interview

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

The following is an interview question... how can you start solve this kind of a question ? is there a general algorithm for such a questions ?

The question is to explain what this method does. I know what she gives for some inputs I tried (and it's OK), but I really don't know how to start solve this kind of a questions...

```
public boolean what (int num) 
{ 
    boolean ans = true; 

    for (int x = 2; (x*x <= num) && ans; x=x+1) 
    {
        if ((num % x) == 0) 
            ans = false; 
    } 

    return ans; 
}
```

thx !

Comment: did and got results with no meaning to me... this results were good, because I tested it on a real comp...

Comment: A reversed eng. just try some inputs and try to use some common sense, no other optional way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse engeering process you can follow, provide the some sample input and get the output by which you can determine the result.

Choose your input sensibly so that it would easy to solve the problem.

In present case -

Input : 1  return : true
Input : 2  return : true
Input : 3  return : true
Input : 4  return : false
Input : 5  return : true
...
Input : 9  return : false //aha...it seems to be prime number 
...
Input : 111  return : false

So in this case its prime number logic.

Comment: So you're saying that the real deal here is just trying some common math issues it should do and try to check them out ?

Comment: yah... in other terms

Answer (score 2):

let num = 10

```
public boolean what (int num) 
{ 
    boolean ans = true; 

    for (int x = 2; (x*x <= num) && ans; x=x+1) 
{              //^ multiply x with x will give (4,9).. When x = 4, than (16<= num) = false
    if ((num % x) == 0) // divide 10 by (2,3) if reminder is zero that means 10 is not prime
        ans = false; // set ans to false so that for loop can be terminated or just break;
} 

return ans;
```

}

Comment: 10 is a prime number ?

Comment: @KamleshArya that was little typo in hurry

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that x runs through the sequence 4, 6, 8, ...

Comment: it should be 4,9,16,25 ?

Comment: Yaa man.. again did a mistake.. changing it

Comment: Well, still not correct, the square will just be used for termination of the loop. x runs through 2,3,4,5, ...

Comment: @Henry Thats correct man

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the `num` is a prime.

To find out what a method does read the code and try to understand what it is doing. You may also try some inputs. For good code the names of variables and methods also help a lot (which is not the case here).

However, if the method implements an algorithm you do not know and you do not know the context of the problem that is being solved you probably never find out what it does.

Comment: can you explain the way I can get to this answer ? (ran it already on paper)...

Comment: The name of vars and method in purpose says nothing... this is a challenge question, therefore there is no name for them...

Answer (score 1):

You can find it running the method with several random inputs,
and try to find the relation between `INPUT` you gave and `OUTPUT` that appeared.

Before getting to conclusion just check it Known Output first and then declare your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the above program initially the number is assumed to be not prime. If any number greater than 2 and less than or equal to the square root of the number divide the given number then the number is not prime.

The method returns true if the number is not prime and returns false if the number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of method : to find out prime numbers.

This method gives an output of  booleaan ans = 'true' , if input number is prime number. 
Else it gives a return value of false.

It follows the simplest logic to find out if a number is prime or not..

for example if a number is 11 , 
Step 1 - we multiply it with a num till (num*num) is smaller than 11. {no need to test beyond value bigger then num*num, as all possible cases are tested }.

Step 2 - check if remainder of dividing 11/2 is zero or not , if remainder is not 0 then 11 is not prime.if it divides we go back to step 1

So the loop will be ..

Step 1 num = 11 , x = 2

Step 2 11%2 != 0 so goto step 1 , num undivisible

Step 1 num =11 , x = 3

Step2 11%3 != 0

Step 1 num = 11 , x = 4 but x*x = 16 and 16> 11 so no more looping and 11 is prime as it wasn't divisible with any number till x=3.

another example can be 38.. 
step 1 num 38 , x=2

step 2 38%2 ==0 , so remainder = zero and ans = false thus no more looping through and '38' is not prime.

a more advanced approach to finding a number if its prime or not could be to test its divisibility only against prime numbers. which is actually more efficient in case we have quite bigger numbers as input.

```
public boolean what (int num) // number to be tested is passed
{ 
boolean ans = true;   // default value
        for (int x = 2; (x*x <= num) && ans; x=x+1) //looping till num is found divisibl 
        {
            if ((num % x) == 0) 
            ans = false;   // ans is false in case num is not prime
        } 
        return ans; // num is prime
}
```

Hope the explanation helps.. message me in case of any doubt or help.